# Proving inequality equivalence using propositional logic: stuck with redundancy at the end of the proof + circularity problem

Tags: arithmetic, propositional-calculus

I would like to prove formally that : ~ ( a is less than b or equal to b) is equivalent to ( a is strictly greater than b ).

But I cannot get rid of a redundant conjoint at the end of the proof.

Other problem: at line (3) I seem obliged to admit trichotomy law. But is not assuming this law tentamount to reasoning circularly?

Which proposition should be taken as primitive in order not to fall into circularity?

~ ( a is strictly less than b OR a is equal to b)

<==> ~ (a < b)  & ~(a = b)

<==> (a > b or a =  b) & ~( a = b)

<==> (a > b & ~ a = b ) OR ( a=b & ~ a = b)

<==> (a > b & ~ a = b) OR FALSE

<==> (a > b & ~ a=b)

Comment: Step $3$ is circular indeed. It uses the very thing you need to prove, with just $a$ and $b$ interchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But **it is** trichotomy law :

> $(a < b \lor a=b \lor a > b)$.

Rewrite it as : $(a < b \lor a=b) \lor (a > b)$ and using [Material Implication rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) we get :

> $\lnot (a < b \lor a=b) \to (a > b)$.

And vice versa.